# Not sure how to compile compass related files for Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, compass-sass, electron

I'm recently rewriting an existing HTML5 web app to desktop app.

I find electron is much more suitable for my task, but my existing web application includes compass files (config.rb files and sass etc) that need to be compiled.

Not sure how to config that in Electron.

Need help here, thanks!

Comment: Since on the fly compilation would be a little tricky, I suggest that you precompile your stylesheets using [`node-sass`](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) and deliver your app with already compiled files. Or if you want to have it on the fly you can use [`electron-compile`](https://github.com/electronjs/electron-compile) package

Comment: Ditto what @YanFoto said. use node-sass or other means to compile to the desired language.

Comment: Curious, was this a rails app originally?